# Using Oracle with Heroku

Tags: oracle, heroku

Our application contains Tomcat application server that connects and use Oracle DB.
I would like to check the option to migrate our application to Heroku.
I would like to know if and how Heroku is supporting Oracle server.

Thank you,
Moshe

Comment: does heroku allow jdbc connection to Oracle? Does your application deploy on Heroku?

Comment: Our application is using JDBC and will be deployed on Heroku. We would like to deploy also teh DB server on Heroku. There is option like this?

Comment: Normally you define a jdbc connection pool where the app can fetch connections from. This is the case in glassfish and WebLogic. Don't know about heroku but if it is something serious, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku hosting services do not support Oracle database..

Answer (score 1):

From Heroku main page: Heroku supports Ruby, Node.js, Python, and Java 
You can connect to oracle from all these languages. 
For Java (based on mentioning of Tomcat), you will be using jdbc.